# dynamic_sidebar() stopped working

Tags: templates, sidebar

A custom page template which has been in use for 3 or 4 years which rendered a custom sidebar has suddenly stopped rendering it. I can't for the life work out what the problem is.

```
/* functions.php */

/**
 * Register Areas sidebars and widgetized areas.
 *
 */
function my_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'My Sidebar',
        'id'            => 'my_sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div><div>&nbsp;</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widgets_init' );

/* wordpress page template file*/
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'my_sidebar' ) ) : ?>
    <div>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'my_sidebar' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the Wordpress dashboard, 3 or 4 widgets are assigned to the area as would be expected. But calling dynamic_sidebar() renders an empty string.

Any ideas?

*** UPDATE ***

This is the output of the debugging code provided in the first response.

```
Sidebar ID: new_sidebar ( Active)
Sidebar Found
4 Widgets Found

All Sidebars Widgets:
Array
(
    [wp_inactive_widgets] => Array
        (
            [0] => calendar-4
            [1] => rss-3
            [2] => em_calendar-4
            [3] => recent-posts-2
        )

    [hca_alert_area] => Array
        (
        )

  [SNIP - other sidebars]

    [new_sidebar] => Array
        (
            [0] => search-2
            [1] => nav_menu-2
            [2] => em_widget-2
            [3] => recent-posts-3
        )

    [footer-sidebar] => Array
        (
            [0] => nav_menu-3
        )

    [array_version] => 3
)
```

I've spent a crazy amount of time trying to work out the problem. The site uses a no-longer supported version of the Cherry Framework template. I'm reluctant to update the entire theme purely because of this glitch if I can fix it.

Comment: you are checking 'is_active_sidebar' with a different id than used in 'dynamic _sidebar' - is that on purpose? have you done any updates or changed any plugins

Comment: That was a typo. Nope nothing has changed. Wordpress is recognising that the sidebar exists, but appears not to be finding any widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case like this, you're probably going to need to check the conditions in `dynamic_sidebar` to find out what is not happening.

```
if (isset($_GET['debugsidebar'])) {add_action('init', 'debug_sidebar');}  
function debug_sidebar() {

    $id = $_GET['debugsidebar'];
    $sidebarswidgets = get_option('sidebars_widgets');

    if (is_active_sidebar($id)) {$status = " Active";} else {$status = "Inactive";}
    echo "Sidebar ID: ".$id." (".$status.")<br>";
    if (array_key_exists($id, $sidebarswidgets)) {
        $found = "Sidebar Found";
        if (is_array($sidebarswidgets[$id])) {
            $widgets = count($sidebarswidgets[$id])." Widgets Found";
        } else {$widgets = "Widget Array not Found!";}
        echo $found."<br".$widgets."<br>";
    else {echo "Sidebar Not Found<br>";}

    echo "<br>All Sidebars Widgets: ".print_r($sidebarswidgets,true)."<br>"; 
    exit;
}
```

Which you put in your theme `functions.php` and then can check via `http://example.com/?debugsidebar=my_sidebar`

There is a small difference in the bugout checks is `is_active_sidebar` and `dynamic_sidebar`

From `is_active_sidebar` function:

```
! empty( $sidebars_widgets[ $index ] );
```

From `dynamic_sidebar` function:

```
if ( empty( $wp_registered_sidebars[ $index ] ) || empty( $sidebars_widgets[ $index ] ) || ! is_array( $sidebars_widgets[ $index ] ) ) {
```

Since the middle condition is the same, this means that either the sidebar is not being registered correctly (unlikely as that seems fine) - but more likely, the data for that key is not an array of widgets. You will find out from running the debug function.

It may possibly show you a mismatch or corrupt data in the `sidebars_widgets` option value (If needs be you can that check against a value from you `wp_options` table backup from when it was working.)

Comment: Brilliant - thanks so much for this, it's perfect.

Comment: Although this debugging code is really helpful,  I am still stuck with regard to finding out why no widgets are output to the browser. Nothing seems to be out of place or corrupt. See additional data added to the original question.

Comment: You could create a copy of the function `dynamic_sidebar` and call it `dynamic_sidebar_test` or whatever, and call that in your template, then debug it line by line by adding output in the copied function for each condition to track down where it is failing.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. Your two suggestions allowed me to diagnose the problem, which was a single line in the now unsupported 'Cherry Framework' code. I'm putting the exact solution in another answer, in case it helps anybody, but I'm marking this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines in the obsolete Cherry Plugin (Version 9.2.8.1, which does not support PHP 7+ in theory) caused sidebars to be hidden all the time.

**In file**: `wordpress/wp-content/plugins/cherry-plugin/includes/widgets/widgets-manager.php`

**Comment out the following code:**

```
add_filter( 'widget_display_callback', 'maybe_hide_widget', 10, 3 );
function maybe_hide_widget( $instance, $widget_object, $args ) {
if ( ! check_widget_visibility( $args['widget_id'] ) )
    return false;
    return $instance;
}
```

It would also be possible to edit the `check_widget_visibility()` function (obviously) in the same file so that it did not always return false and continued to function as intended. However, for my purposes, simply disabling the entire mechanism was good enough.